# Return a value from a Alamofire closure

Tags: ios, swift, return, closures, alamofire

i have this function called `sendRequest` in a class called `A` and this `sendRequest` function returns a `Any` object and in first line i created a variable like this `var serverResponse = JSON()` and i have this code to request

```
upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                })
       upload.responseJSON { response in

       print(response.response?.statusCode as Any)

       if(response.result.isSuccess){
            serverResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print("Success\(serverResponse)")

       }else{
            serverResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print("No Success\(serverResponse)")
       }
  }
```

the above code is inside the `sendRequest` function and at the end/outside of this closure i have a return statement returning the server response `return serverResponse`

and i am accessing this function from class `B` i created an object of class `A` now i have this code in class B

```
var response: Any =  request.sendRequest("url", parameters: body, headers: [:])
```

now the problem is the response variable here will always have an empty `JSON` object and i think thats because in the `closure` the `api` call is being processed in the background so before the result comes from the server the `return` statement gets executed giving me an empty `JSON` object on class `B`

and i tried returning the `serverResponse` in the `if` statement where i checked if its successful or not and gives me an error like this:

```
Unexpected non-void return value in void function
```

so how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. It is being returned empty because it is being run on the background thread. When making network requests we therefor tend to use `completionBlocks` Swift 5 implemented the new typ of `Result<Any, Error>` which is really convenient.

Try implementing `completion((Result<Any, Error>) -> ())` in your function params instead. When you get the response you unwrap it my writing:

```
switch result {
    case .succeses(let data):
    //Do something
    break
    case .failure(let error):
    //Do something
    break
}
```

As you are inside the actual block you can't execute a return statement. That's the error you are getting. The block itself doesn't ask for a return. Unlike `map, filter, reduce` etc.